# Angular Router - Why Do You Need App Root and Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Angular Router defines a directive called `router-outlet` which renders a specified component in that spot if it's the route loaded by the router.

Since you can define a base root (`/`), one would assume you no longer need a bootstrap component since the router can now put your parent component on the DOM.

Yet, if you do not define a bootstrap component, you get an error:

> `The module AppModule was bootstrapped, but it does not declare "@NgModule.bootstrap" components nor a "ngDoBootstrap" method.`

One also assumes that the `AppModule`, if it is bootstrapped, should be bootstrapped to the `<app-root/>` tag (by convention).

I don't understand. How is the app supposed to work if the app bootstraps *and* the router is routing? Won't this lead to double components, etc? If the app is being rendered into the `router-outlet`, then what is the `app-root` tag doing?

Comment: Where do you put the router outlet? Not in the app component template?

Comment: I think it is a good question. We could use the router-outlet directive right in the index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

Angular CLI has some default conventions, but they can be overidden.  One of them is that your main NgModule is called AppModule and your top level component is called AppComponent.  These can be customized.  See your main.ts file and app.module.ts files.
main.ts:

```
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The main.ts file is boostraping the AppModule by default (again you can override it)

Here is a pertenat part from the app.module.ts:

```
    @NgModule({
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Angular must bootstrap before routing works.  Once it bootstraps it looks into the DOM to see where it should attach the bootstraped component.  That is, it looks into the DOM and looks for the `<app-root>` element because (by default) your AppComponent is the bootstrap component (defined in AppModule), the app component has a default selector of "app-root".

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class...
```

**Usually you want your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element to be in your app.component.html file.  This doesn't cause double components.**

The Angular runtime environment must ***bootstrap*** before your app is executing in the browser.  And Angular's routing module will only work once Angular's runtime is executing.

[Angular Module Bootstraping](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping)